# What does "where T : somevalue" mean?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

What does `where T : somevalue` mean? I just saw some code that said `where T : Attribute`. I think this has something to do with generics but I am not sure what this means or what it is doing.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is a [**constraint on a type parameter**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), meaning that the type `T` given to a generic class or method must inherit from the class `Attribute`

For example:

```
public class Foo<T> : 
   where T : Attribute
{
    public string GetTypeId(T attr) { return attr.TypeId.ToString(); }
 // ..
}

Foo<DescriptionAttribute> bar; // OK, DescriptionAttribute inherits Attribute
Foo<int> baz; // Compiler error, int does not inherit Attribute
```

This is useful, because it allows the generic class to do things with objects of type `T` with the knowledge that anything that is a `T` must also be an `Attribute`.

In the example above, it's okay for `GetTypeId` to query the `TypeId` of `attr` because `TypeId` is a property of an `Attribute`, and because `attr` is a `T` it must be a type that inherits from `Attribute`.

Constraints can also be used on generic methods, with the same effect:

```
public static void GetTypeId<T>(T attr) where T : Attribute
{
   return attr.TypeId.ToString();
}
```

There are other constraints you can place on a type; from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

> `where T: struct`
>
> The type argument must be a value
>   type. Any value type except Nullable
>   can be specified.
>
> `where T : class`
>
> The type argument must be a reference
>   type; this applies also to any class,
>   interface, delegate, or array type.
>
> `where T : new()`
>
> The type argument must have a public
>   parameterless constructor. When used
>   together with other constraints, the
>   new() constraint must be specified
>   last.
>
> `where T : <base class name>`
>
> The type argument must be or derive
>   from the specified base class.
>
> `where T : <interface name>`
>
> The type argument must be or implement
>   the specified interface. Multiple
>   interface constraints can be
>   specified. The constraining interface
>   can also be generic.
>
> `where T : U`
>
> The type argument supplied for T must
>   be or derive from the argument
>   supplied for U. This is called a naked
>   type constraint.

Comment: +1 This is quite compreshensive.  I wish I can favorite an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally what the others said, you have the following too:

- new() - T must have default constructor
- class - T must be a reference type
- struct - T must be a value type

Answer (score 1):

The [**where**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8(VS.80).aspx) clause is used to limit the arguments that can be passed when using generics. When you create a generic class it might be in your best interest to specify an argument type depending on how you plan to use T in your class. If it anything besides what System.Object can do then it is probably best to use a [**constraint**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) as you will get a compile time error vs a runtime.

example

If you create a class

```
class Person<T> where T : System.IComparable<T>
{
   //can now use CompareTo
}
```

You can not not pass this class anything that does not implement IComparable. So it is now safe to use CompareTo on anything that is passed into the the Person class.

Answer (score 1):

It's a way of restricting the type used as generic arguments. So:

```
where T : SomeType
```

Means that T must either derive from **SomeType** or implement the interface **SomeType**