# What does where T : name of type mean?

Tags: c#

I see code like this many times:

```
 public class BaseList<T> : List<T> where T : BaseBE
```

My question is what is meaning of this code and why do we write this line like this? I know it is using `List<T>` but what is the meaning of `where T : BaseBE`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "where T : somevalue" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622264/what-does-where-t-somevalue-mean)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This statement `where T:BaseBE` is a constraint over what `T` can be. In this specific case, it's telling you that `T` can be of type `BaseBE`or from any class inheriting from it, but nothing else.

For more details you could check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx), you'll find much more details and examples.

Comment: hello @claudio redi please give me some tips what i have to do improve my programing and how can i learn more and from where?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the generic type T must inherit from BaseBE, this is called a type constraint. This allows the type T to be used as a BaseBE within BaseList.

So for example:

```
class Foo { }

BaseList<Foo> myList; // Wont compile, Foo is not a BaseBE

class Bar : BaseBE { }

BaseList<Bar> myOtherList; // Ok Bar is a BaseBE
```

You can read about more types of constraint here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx

E.g where T : new() means T must have a public parameterless constructor.